# Proving two definitions of continuity are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

I think that these definitions of continuity are equivalent, but I'm not sure how to create a mathematical proof to convey this.

The first definition states that:

A function $f$ is continuous at a point $x=c$ if for every sequence ($a_n$)$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that converges to $c$ such that ($a_n$) $\not=$ $c$ for all $n$, the sequence ($f$($a_n$))$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $f(c)$. If a function is continuous at every point of some set $S,$ we say that $f$ is continuous on $S.$

The second definition, the delta-epsilon definition, states that:

A function $f$ is said to be continuous at a point, $x$ if for every $\epsilon$>0 there exists a $\delta$>0 such that

|$f(y)-f(x)$|< $\epsilon$ for all $y$ such that |$y-x$|< $\delta$.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a pretty standard question. I am sure it is already asked and answered many times on stackexchange.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint 1:**

If $f$ is delta-epsilon continuous and $(a_n)$ is such a sequence then given any $\varepsilon > 0$ you are looking for an $N$ such that if $n \ge N$ then

$$ |f(a_n) - f(c)| < \varepsilon. $$

Note that this looks similar to the inequality

$$ |f(x) - f(c)| < \varepsilon. $$

**Hint 2:**

For the converse direction, use the contrapositive. That is, assume $f$ is not continuous with the delta-epsilon definition. **Write down what it means for $f$ not to satisfy the delta-epsilon definition without using the word "not" anywhere.**

Now let $\delta_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and allow yourself to pick $a_n$ such that

$$ 0 < |a_n - c| < \delta_n \text{ but } |f(a_n) - f(c)| > \varepsilon_0 $$

where $\varepsilon_0 > 0$ is a fixed constant. Derive a contradiction.